# ERROR: Not enough arguments for format string

Tags: python, mysql, csv, mysql-python

My CSV file contains data like this:

```
Date,portfolioValue,pID,FinancialInstrument
2018-03-27,4937.395022140785,1,Oil
2018-03-28,4937.395022140785,1,Oil
```

My insert execution code is as follows:

```
file = open(portfolio_file,'r')
    csv_data = csv.reader(file, delimiter =',')
    for row in df_header:
        print(row)
        #stmt = ("INSERT INTO PredictionData (Date, Open, Settle, High, Low, HorizonType, InstrumentName, PredictorType) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Open=%s, Settle=%s, High=%s, Low=%s")
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO portfolioData(Date, portfolioValue, pID, FinancialInstrument) VALUES (DATE_FORMAT('%s','%%Y-%%m-%%d'), '%s', '%s', '%s') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE portfolioValue ='%s'", row)
        cnx.commit()
```

When I am running this I keep getting raise errorclass(errorvalue)
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: not enough arguments for format string

I have the same number of columns and formatting the date properly.

Comment: Looks like each row has 4 items but your format string has 5 `%s` placeholders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the SQL text to reference the value that would have been inserted (if the insert had succeeded), using the special `VALUES()` function, like this

```
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE portfolioValue = VALUES(portfolioValue)
```

then there's no need to pass an extra second copy of the value

Answer (score 0):

like @pault said, you need 5 items (because of the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE portfolioValue ='%s'` towards the end).

Just make a copy of your portfolioValue as the 5th item, for each row.

Comment: This is what I have now: cursor.execute("INSERT INTO portfolioData(Date, portfolioValue, pID, FinancialInstrument) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE portfolioValue ='%s'", row) but on insertion it tries to insert 'e' from Date into portfolioValue.

Comment: I am getting this now after I removed the '' around the value for portfolioValue _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1136, "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1")